# fork wget 's with ability to control specific downloads

Tags: linux, bash, unix, fork, wget

I'm writing a bash script, aka download-manager.
       Point of interest is make this simple lines more advanced:

```
for link in ${links}; do
    wget -q --show-progress ${link}
done
```

1. How to **fork** all downloads **and provide for script-user a friendly way to kill one specific download** after all has started?
2. Does *wget -bqc* run in parallel or not?
3. Is there anything to use something instead *--show-progress* to provide ability for script-user to **show current status of specific download**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So idea is:

```
 #declare associative array  [download_url]=pid_of_download      
 declare -A downloads
 #declare array of killed downloads
 declare -a killedDownloads=()

 function download() {
  local url=$1     
  # killed downloads can be reloaded, but not successfully downloaded URL's
  if [ ${downloads[${url}]} ] && [[ ! ${killedDownloads[*]} =~ ${do wnloads[${url}]} ]]; then
     echo "Already download-[ing/ed] !"
  else  
    wget -q ${url} &
    downloads[${url}]=$!
  fi
 }
```

**$!** contains the process ID of the most recently executed background command, obviously PID of just executed ***wget*** command

When user wants to kill some download, we print all download array. While printing, we can also show status obtained as a substring from

```
 jobs -l | grep ${downloads[$i])
```

...and use **killedDownloads** to know which URLs was actually killed, not finished.

```
 if [[ ${killedDownloads[*]} =~ ${downloads[$i]} ]]
 //set status var to killed
```

Kill itself :

```
 function stop(){
     local pid=$1

     if ps -p ${pid} > /dev/null; then
        kill -9 ${pid}
        wait ${pid} 2>/dev/null
        echo "Killed downloading of ${pid}"
        killedDownloads+=${pid}
     else
        echo "No active download with id = ${pid} exists"
     fi
   }
```

And of course you'll need to put this inside some interactive loop, add checks for invalid urls, etc.